# Iterate overs MAP Entry elements attached to ArrayList using JAVA 8

Tags: lambda, java-8

How I can iterate over values of a MAP Entry attached to an ArrayList. (List<Map<Set, Map.Entry<String, Object>>>)
I am new in java 8 and I want to get values of that MAP Entry by using lambda expressions.
I want to avoid this statement used by java older than version 8.

```
    List<Object> listeDesValeurs = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listExtractQglobal.size(); i++) {
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : listExtractQglobal.get(i)
                .entrySet()) {
listeDesValeurs.add(entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Thank you very much indeed!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the above code in Java 8 style (with lambda expression and method references), you could write it like the following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> myMapsList = new ArrayList<>(); // My list, consisting of maps
        Map<String, Object> someSampleMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        someSampleMap.put("bla", new Object());
        myMapsList.add(someSampleMap);
        List<Object> resultsList = new ArrayList<Object>(); // The list that I want to put all my mal values into
        resultsList = myMapsList.stream().flatMap(myMap -> myMap.entrySet().stream()).map(Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(resultsList.size()); // should print out 1, since the arraylist myMapsList only has one map which in turn has only one entry
    }
}
```